# What song is playing in Naruto Shippuden episode 114 at 17:54?

Tags: naruto, music

There's a song playing in Naruto Shippuden episode 114 at 17:54 while Orochimaru is trying to take over Sasuke's body with the transference ritual but Sasuke overcomes him instead.

Answer (score 0):

The song is Sasuke's ninja way

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AastZeIJJDA&ab_channel=quinny366